# How to put an associate array in input name tag in html and display it using php? -I'm using loop to display 5 textboxes

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, input

i'm working with my POST and Commenting system for my software engineering project. How can i put an associate array in input name tag  and display it on the next page using php.

This is my code according to what i have searched: (**Not Working**)

**Try.php**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action = "Try2.php" method = "POST">
        <?php
        $x = 1;

        while ($x <= 5){
            echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'thes[ths][]'>";

            $x++;
        }
        ?>
        <input type = "submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Try2.php**

```
<?php

$a = $_POST['thes[ths][3]'];

echo "$a";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = $_POST['thes']['ths'][3];

echo "$a";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['thes']['ths'] as $key=>$val){
    echo $key.":".$val."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Care to explain what your answer does?

Comment: extract the values submitted from the first page, in reason to check it and see what's your needs...